# drf-yasg how to display the api description outside?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I want the describe in there:
[image: picture 1]
  but mine is in there:
[image: picture 2]
This is my code:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='GET', manual_parameters=[project_param])
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_project_info(request):
    """
    获取项目信息
    """
```

Version info:
Django==2.2.1
drf-yasg==1.16.1

Answer (score 3):

if Docstring used in below format description will be available in there:

```
class ProductOperation(ModelViewSet):
   """
   Outside

   Inside

   """
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's work. So in order to do this, I must wirite the description twice?

Comment: No ; use some character such as dot Or hidden char in up or downside .  @shuiqiang

Answer (score 1):

you can use `swagger_auto_schema` decorator to display id, summary and description.

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

class ProductOperation(ModelViewSet):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_id='Display end of opblock',
        operation_summary="Display outside",
        operation_description='Display inside',
    )
    def action_one(self, request):
        dosomething()
```

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvIK2.png)